# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module

Tags: java, angularjs, weblogic, portal

On a Weblogic portal I am getting error.

Details - not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

How to overcome this, as  my url is showing some different content ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is because you failed to instantiate a module or inject a dependency that you are using.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But after clearing cache it is working fine. And also working fine for first time only and not after that.